# Unable to locate package libqt5webkit5-dev

Tags: qt, containers

Suddenly today, without us changing any configuration, all test containers began to fail because of the following error:

```
$ sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install libqt5webkit5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libqt5webkit5-dev
E: Unable to locate package qtdeclarative5-dev
```

We have the following configuration in our .travis.yml in order to use QT5 on Travis with Ubuntu 12.04:

```
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-sdk-team
    packages:
      - libqt5webkit5-dev
      - qtdeclarative5-dev
```

We've tried to fix this but are baffled. Any ideas? Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Qt has deprecated WebKit, so maybe an overzealous package manager has removed it from the repos.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem and after contacting Travis support I learned that apparently the ubuntu-sdk-team has stopped providing packages for Precise and you need to switch dist to Trusty. In order to get the builds working again add this to your .travis.yml file

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 will be deprecated in [less than a year from now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases) (exactly at 2017-04-26), and also Qt Webkit is deprecated with the new versions of Qt starting from [Qt 5.5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5#Deprecated_Functionality). It is removed in Qt 5.6 from the Qt distribution:

> With 5.6, Qt WebKit and Qt Quick 1 will no longer be supported and are
>   dropped from the release. The source code for these modules will still
>   be available. You can continue to compile and use these modules, but
>   we will not be supporting them any longer.
>
> http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/03/16/qt-5-6-released/

So, you in order to maintain the stability of your development environment, either you have to stay with the current versions of Ubuntu and Qt (which has its own issues), or you have to port your code to work with the newer versions of Ubuntu and Qt, like Qt 5.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.